# React Router returns me a blank web page not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am facing a problem. I am trying to use React Router but it keeps showing me a blank page. Here is my code:

App.js:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'; 
import ConceptosBasicos from "./components/ConceptosBasicos";


function App(){
 return(
     <div>
      <h1>React Router</h1>
      <a href="https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start" 
      target="_blank" 
      rel="noreferrer"
      >
        Documentación</a>
        <hr/>
        <ConceptosBasicos/>
      </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

ConceptosBásicos.js:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';


const ConceptosBasicos=() =>{
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Conceptos Básicos</h2>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/">
        <h3>Home</h3>
        <p>Bienvenid@s al tema de las Rutas en React</p>
       </Route>
       <Route exact path="/acerca">
        <h3>Acerca</h3>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/contacto">
        <h3>Contacto</h3>
      </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </div>
  );
};

export default ConceptosBasicos;
```

I've installed "React Router V6", can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thanks for all the helpers.

Comment: Kindly check this [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change all your `<Route/>` as below

- you don't require to put `exact` as in V6 its by default [read more here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/)
- you have to put what `elements` / `components` are to be rendered when path matches in an `element` prop

  ```
  <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={
       <>
         <h3>Home</h3>
         <p>Bienvenid@s al tema de las Rutas en React</p>
       </>
     }/>
     <Route path="/acerca" element={<h3>Acerca</h3>}/>
     <Route path="/contacto" element={<h3>Contacto</h3>}/>
  </Routes>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

the new way to write react router is

```
<BrowserRouter> 
      <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}
      </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```